# How to exclude a TDS project in the deployment

Tags: tds, deployment

We are using Azure DevOps and want to exclude a TDS project (`Sample.Project.Content.Master`) in the solution. This project has content items which should not go to the target environments.

In the Build project's General section, `Sample.Project.Content.Master` is excluded.
[image]

Select `Deploy items changed after`

[image]

The "Package Generation Options" is set to `Generate only an item package`.

[image]

In the VS Solution's configuration properties, excluded this project.

[image]

But still, when the pipeline is built, the content items are generated and are being deployed to the target environments.

Comment: Did you check this using `Deployment Property Manager`? Here you can see how to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293954/sitecore-how-to-exclude-particular-dll-from-the-tds-package#:~:text=Second%20Way%3A-,In%20the%20TDS%20project%20explorer%20select%20the%20item%20that%20you,two%20values%3A%20Include%20or%20Exclude.

Comment: Also here is the article given by JammyKam that you can use. https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/20/excluding-sitecore-assemblies-from-deployment/

Comment: Check this too - https://blogs.perficient.com/2013/12/08/setting-up-a-sitecore-solution-part-2-tds-and-build-configurations/

Comment: If it helps, you can control this at item level too by going to item Properties in visual studio and then marking it as Never Deploy or Deploy Once.